# What sites have different ratings for different time controls for Chess960?

Tags: chess-variants, online-chess, chess960, recommendations

Both lichess and chess.com and have ratings for live chess960, but this is regardless of time control. Please recommend a site that has separate ratings for different time controls for chess960.

There are always multiple accounts (I actually messaged both lichess and chess.com and then they approved me) or actually playing only rapid on one site and then only blitz on another, but come on.

Answer (score 1):

Chess.com will actually now give separate ratings for bullet/blitz/rapid for variants like 960. But you must go into the "4 player and variants" part of the site. If you play 960 on the regular part of the site (which it still lets you do) it just gives you one 960 rating as always.